# How do I turn a Java SQL query into a Java Object [][]?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, object

I'm looking for a way to query a SQL database with Java and return an Object [][]. Here is the SQL query:

```
 private static Object result[][] = null;
 result = run.query(conn, "select * from TREEDATA", rsh);
```

Here is the sample of what the data should mirror:

```
    Object[][] table = {
        {1, null, "Root"}, //i=0
        {2, 1, "Node2"}, //i=1
        {3, 2, "Node3"}, //i=2
        {4, 3, "Node4"}, //i=3
        {5, 4, "Node5"}, //i=4
        {6, 5, "Node6"}, //i=5
        {7, 6, "Node7"}, //i=6
        {8, 1, "Node8"}, //i=7
        {9, 1, "Node9"}, //i=8
        {10, 9, "Node10"},};    //i=9
```

Here is the result set handler with the code that I cannot figure out:

```
    public Object[][] handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        if (!rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("result set is null");
            return null;
        }
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int rows = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            rows++;
        }
        Object[][] result = new Object[rows];
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
 //How do I do what I need to do in order to return result[][] 
            result[i][] = rs.getObject(3);           
            System.out.println(result[i][2].toString());
        }
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation like you started it:

```
    public Object[][] handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        if (!rs.last()) { //If false, the result set is empty.
            System.out.println("result set is null");
            return null;
        }
        int rowCount = rs.getRow(); // You are pointing on the last row, so this will get the row number of the last row.
        rs.beforeFirst(); // Reset your cursor.
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
        Object[][] result = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                result[i][j] = rs.getObject(j);
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

But personally I would rather have the function return `ArrayList<Object[]>` or even better `List<TreeData>` but then you need to implement and fill the `TreeData` object with row values manually. Which is where JPA/Hibernate comes in.. But that might be overkill again depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

In your function start with using an `ArrayList` and not an `Object[][]`. So you don't need to count rows.

Then for every row

```
while(rs.next()) {
  Object[] row = new Object[meta.getColumnCount()];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < row.length ; ++i) {
    row[i] = rs.getObject(i+1); // remember thet on ResultSet object first column is 1
  }
  rows.add(row); // add row to the ArrayList
}
```

At the end you can convert your `ArrayList` in array with `toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? You need to reset the result set before you loop through to get the data.

```
Object[][] result = new Object[rows];
rs.first();
int i = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
  result[i] = new Object[3];
  result[i][0] = rs.getObject(1);
  result[i][1] = rs.getObject(2);
  result[i][2] = rs.getObject(3);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: His query use `select *` so you cannot be sure that the columns will be always 3.

Comment: agreed, a for loop is a more robust solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lot of operations on the output, and want the data to be column-like, you might want to look into the tablesaw library: https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/userguide/importing_data.html

It basically is something like Python's [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) library to handle any grid-like data using DataFrames.

Using tablesaw, importing SQL is then easy:

```java
String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:CoffeeDB;create=true";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

Table customer = null; 
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
  try (ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    customer = Table.read().db(results, "Customer");
  }
}
```

Then you can easily access all the data in the `customer` Table:

```
                                                           Customers                                                           
 orderid   |  custid  |       sales_datetime       |  locid  |  cnt  |       visit_datetime       |       exit_datetime        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 28624025  |     154  |  2023-12-24T07:36:33.000Z  |      10  |    20  |  2023-12-24T08:30:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T08:25:05.000Z  |
 28624434  |     153  |  2023-12-24T09:40:42.000Z  |      10  |    19  |  2023-12-24T10:00:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T09:58:25.000Z  |
 28625216  |     154  |  2023-12-24T09:53:09.000Z  |      10  |    21  |  2023-12-24T10:30:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T10:33:03.000Z  |
 28625217  |     154  |  2023-12-24T09:53:38.000Z  |      10  |    20  |  2023-12-24T10:34:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T10:37:54.000Z  |
 28625616  |     153  |  2023-12-24T09:39:51.000Z  |      10  |    21  |  2023-12-24T10:46:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T10:43:50.000Z  |
 28635354  |     154  |  2023-12-24T07:02:08.000Z  |      10  |    17  |  2023-12-24T07:34:00.000Z  |  2023-12-24T07:35:47.000Z  |
```

Then read the tablesaw docs, how to easily access everything in this table.